# SyntaxError: unexpected token ':' (colon) typescript webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

has anyone else had this issue?

```
(node:24328) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///Users/xxx19/Documents/projects/planning-poker/src/server.ts:13
wss.on('connection', (ws: WebSocket) => {
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:84:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:36:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! game-library@1.0.0 server: `tsc && node ./src/server.ts`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the game-library@1.0.0 server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is my package.json.

I am running `npm run server` which is `"tsc && node ./src/server.ts"`.

Running `npm run tsc` does not show any errors.

```
{
  "name": "game-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint '*/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --inline --config webpack.config.cjs",
    "server": "tsc && node ./src/server.ts",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.cjs",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "ws": "^7.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.9.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.6",
    "@types/ws": "^7.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config:

```
'use-strict';
module.exports = {
    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
        modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
            },
        ],
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    },
};
```

ts.config:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "jsx": "react",
  },
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
}
```